Dagger Hilt Incompatibility with Dependency Inversion
In an Android project structured to follow the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) as outlined in the Android Developer's guide on modularization patterns, I've encountered a challenge with Dagger Hilt dependency injections across modules.
The project's architecture initially mixed public abstractions and private implementations across three modules:

:feature:A
:common:B
:lib:C

To adhere to DIP, the project was restructured into:

Public Abstraction modules

:feature:A
:common:B
:lib:C


Private implementation modules

:feature:A:impl
:common:B:impl
:lib:C:impl



Dagger Hilt is utilized for dependency injection, with all bindings located in the impl modules. The issue arises when attempting to inject an implementation from :common:B:impl into :feature:A:impl, where :common:B:impl also requires an injection from :lib:C:impl. While injections work as expected when the implementations and bindings for C remain in :lib:C (not fully adhering to DIP), moving them to :lib:C:impl leads to errors.
The error I encountered is a missing binding error when :common:B:impl needs to be injected into :feature:A:impl:
/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/app/build/generated/hilt/component_sources/projectProdDebug/com/project/app/common/app/ProjectApplication_HiltComponents.java:1054: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.project.app.backend.IServiceProviderFromModuleB cannot be provided without an  method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements StatusVerified.StatusVerifiedComponent,
                         ^

      com.project.app.backend.IServiceProviderFromModuleB is injected at
          [com.project.app.common.app.ProjectApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC] com.project.appdata.network.DataProviderFromModuleA(serviceProvider, …)

This error suggests that Dagger Hilt cannot find a way to provide an instance of IServiceProviderFromModuleB for injection, despite the expected setup in the :common:B:impl module. This scenario typically indicates a misconfiguration or misunderstanding of how Dagger Hilt manages dependencies across modules, especially when adhering to DIP.
I'm seeking insights or solutions to resolve this binding issue, ensuring that the project's structure both adheres to DIP and allows for successful dependency injections across modules using Dagger Hilt.
Does anybody have an idea?

Sounds like your gradle build is misconfigured.  Most likely you don't have the impls from all the required modules in your top level build target.  For exmaple if your top level build is :app,  the build.gradle file for :app needs to include any impl module that is needed to build dagger graph.  In this case it would need lib:C:impl, :feature:A:impl, and common:B:impl.  If it does not have all 3 of them, you get this error because there's no provider for on of the classes.

I've included all necessary modules as dependencies in :app build.gradle file. Hilt still behaves as if the bindings within those modules are missing. I've attempted to add the implementation (:impl) modules as dependencies in other modules that rely on the abstractions, but the issue persists.

That error means it can't find a provider.  Either you actually don't have the gradle dependency list right, you're missing a Hilt binding annotation on the class, or you for some reason aren't running the hilt annotation processor on the module that provides it.  Impossible to tell which of the three it is without a lot of code.  I would also do a completely clean build, sometimes generated dagger files don't get rebuilt properly.  As in don't just trust gradle :app:clean, manually delete the build files and generated source to be sure.

The 3rd option seems the most realistic:


Working Scenario: When the implementation resides within the :lib:C module, Hilt successfully resolves all dependencies.


Failing Scenario: Extracting the implementation to :lib:C:impl and updating the :app module's dependencies to include :lib:C:impl leads to above error.



Then I would compare your :lib:C module's gradle file to its lib:C:impl and see if there's any plugins or annotation processors mentioned in the first but not the second. You can also check out https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html.   A lot of this also depends on how complex your build systems are on top of gradle-  I know at my work we have a whole layer on top of the standard Android stuff to turn off options like that for modules that don't need it to save build time.  So if you have any non-standard systems you may need to ask an expert in your org.

Actually I don't have such advanced configuration. I fixed the problem by renaming :lib:C:impl to :lib:C:impl2, so it was related to that issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847

If that was the problem it sounds like you need to upgrade your gradle version.  That's been fixed for years

I use gradle:8.8, agp:8.2.2

TL;DR:
The issue was caused by having modules with the same name, leading to incorrect Hilt bindings generation - MissingBinding error. Renaming the module from :lib:C:impl to :lib:C:impl2 fixed the problem.
This relates to a known Gradle issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/847, which was supposedly fixed years ago but seems to have resurfaced.
